# Too Complex to determinze exception Java ElasticSearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to make a query in a cluster that has
around 100 indexes (maybe more) and around 6-10 GigaBytes of data from my Java Client.

Elastic Version is: 6.8.23

However, the resulting exception is:

> "too_complex_to_determinize_exception: Determinizing automaton with
> 50607 states and 52156 transitions would result in more than 10000
> states

When the same query (approximately) is ran through Postman (http-9201) no error arises.

Is there any way to set the **max_determinized_state** value in Java Client ?

I am trying this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = null;
    if (negativeSearch) {
        boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(query)
                .maxDeterminizedStates(100000));
        return boolQuery;
    } else {
        boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(query)
                .maxDeterminizedStates(100000));
        bqBuilder = bqBuilder.must(boolQuery);
        return bqBuilder;
    }
```

But it does not seem to work... Am open to any suggestion

**!!UPDATE!!**

Query:

```
"from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": null,
      "disable_coord": false,
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1,
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "+** ",
                  "fields": [],
                  "use_dis_max": true,
                  "tie_breaker": 0,
                  "default_operator": "or",
                  "analyzer": "standard",
                  "auto_generate_phrase_queries": false,
                  "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                  "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
                  "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
                  "phrase_slop": 0,
                  "escape": false,
                  "split_on_whitespace": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            ],
            "disable_coord": false,
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1,
            "must": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: How does your query look like? Could this be the issue? https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/74380

Comment: It looks like something I haven't looked yet. So it might be. I'll look at it and let you know.  Thank you.

Comment: That does not seem to be the issue

Comment: I'm updating the question to include the query as I know in JSON

Comment: So you're querying `+**` in fuzzy mode? Can you explain the use case and the intent behind this query?